# Trouble proving a function homeomorphism in S. G Krantz's Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am learning Topology from SG Krantz ( Dolciaini expository text) and I am unable to prove the function in following example to be homeomorphism.

[image]

> I am unable to prove it either 1-1 or onto. I have proved it continuous.

Inverse of f is  ($ \frac{y} {\sqrt{ \frac{t^2} {x }-1}}$,$ \frac{x} {\sqrt{ \frac{t^2} {y }-1}}$).

It is continuous everywhere when x$\neq$ t or -t or y$\neq$ t or -t. But I have no reason to believe that it must happen. S

It's my humble request to help proving me 1-1 , onto and continuity of inverse.

Thank you.

Comment: You don’t need to show Surjectivity and Injectivity if you know a function $f$ has an inverse $g$. Just show $gf=\operatorname{id}$ and $fg=\operatorname{id}$ and bijectivity of both $f$ and $g$ will follow.

Comment: On the other hand, you should calculate $t$ for both cases, as $t$ only depends on $(x,y)$. Also, after doing it, you should be able to prove that the undesired scenarios can't happen.

Comment: The function $f$ in your question is nothing else than the function $g$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079355.