# Switch map on double suspension is homotopic to the inverse of the cogroup

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $(X,*)$ be a pointed topological space.  The pointed space $\Sigma X$, called *suspension* of $X$, is the quotient space $(X\times I)/S$, where $I=[0,1]$ and $S=(\{*\}\times I)\cup(X\times\{0,1\})\subset X\times I$; the basepoint is the image of $S$.

Now consider $\Sigma^2X$, which is a quotient of $X\times I^2$ where:

- for every $t\in I$, the set $X\times \{0,1\}\times \{t\}$ is identified to a point (meaning a different point for every $t$);
- the set $(\{*\}\times I^2)\cup (X\times \{0,1\}\times I)\cup (X\times I\times \{0,1\})$ is identified to a point, which is the basepoint of $\Sigma^2X$.

The switch map $X\times I^2\to X\times I^2:(x, t, s)\mapsto (x,  s,t)$ is continuous and respects the relations in the two points above, so it induces a continuous map $\sigma:\Sigma^2X\to \Sigma^2X$. It seems, reading some material about cofiber sequences, that $\sigma$ is homotopic to the map $(x,s,t)\mapsto (x,s,1-t)$ (the element $-\rm id$ of the group $[\Sigma^2X,\Sigma^2X]^0$). However I tried to figure out a proof for a while, without success. Do you confirm that there is a homotopy? If yes, would you give me a hint to start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The double suspension is the smash product with $S^2$. You can "ignore" $X$ and just homotope the suspension coordinates (as in, you can get the needed homotopy by smashing with identity map on $X$). Using the stereographic projection, go to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (this pushes the boundary of the square to infinity because it's all collapsed to a point anyway). To go from one coinverse to the other, you need to rotate a quarter turn about $(1/2, 1/2)$. Need to verify that all these maps pass through to the various quotients.

Comment: Thanks @redwhisker now its clearer, I only have another question. We have two maps $\phi, \varphi:S^2\to S^2$, one defined $\phi(s,t)= (s, 1-t)$ and one defined $\varphi(s,t)= (t, s)$, and they are homotopic (in the definition of the maps we view $S^2$ as a quotient of $I^2$). Then as you said, also $1_X\wedge \phi$ (the coinverse) and $1_X\wedge \varphi$ are homotopic. Does a dual argument proves that $X^\phi$ (the inverse of the loop space $\Omega ^2X=X^{S^2}$ and $X^\varphi$ are homotopic?

Comment: Do you mean whether the two maps $\operatorname{Maps}(S^2, X)\to\operatorname{Maps}(S^2, X)$ induced by $\phi, \varphi$ are homotopic? Precomposing with the homotopy between $\phi, \varphi$ works (using an argument with the compact-open topologies).

Comment: That's what I meant, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of more transparent formulae let us use the equivalent definition
$$\Sigma X = X \times J /S$$
with $J =[-1,1]$ and $S = \{*\} \times J \cup X \times \{-1,1\}$.

Let $\partial J^2 = \{-1,1\} \times J \cup J \times  \{-1,1\}$ denote the boundary of $J^2$. Then

$$\Sigma^2 X = X \times J^2 / R $$
with $R = \{*\} \times J^2 \cup X \times \partial J^2$.

For any boundary preserving homotopy $H : J^2 \times I \to J^2$ (which means that $H(\partial J^2 \times I) \subset \partial J^2$) define
$$H^* = id_X \times H : X \times J^2 \times I \to  X \times J^2 .$$
We have $H^*(R \times I) \subset R$, thus $H^*$ induces a homotopy
$$\tilde H : \Sigma^2 X \times I \to \Sigma^2 X .$$

It therefore suffices to show that the switch map
$$\tau : J^2 \to J^2, \tau(s,t) = (t,s)$$
and the reflection map
$$\rho : J^2 \to J^2, \rho(s,t) = (s,-t)$$
are homotopic via a boundary preserving homotopy. Note that $\tau, \rho$ are boundary preserving (which means that they map $\partial J^2$ into itself).

We can do this by proving that $\phi = \tau \circ \rho^{-1}$ and the identity on $J^2$ are homotopic via a boundary preserving homotopy. Note that
$$\phi(s,t) = (-t,s) .$$

Geometrically this a counterclockwise $90^0$-rotation around the center $0$ of the square $J^2$. I shall not write down an explicit homotopy. This is an easy exercise based on the standard homeomorphism

$$h : J^2 \to D^2 .$$
See for example [Homeomorphism between the unit disc and the unit square](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079355).