# Homeomorphism between the first octant of 2-sphere $S^2$ and the ball $B^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It would be great if someone can help me for the proof that $B$ is homeomorphic to the ball $B^2$
where
$$S^2=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1\}$$
$$B=S^2 \cap \{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1 \geq 0,x_2 \geq 0,x_3 \geq 0\} $$
and
$$B^2=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq 1\}$$

My attempt is to project $B$ onto the intersection of the first quadrant of ${\bf R}^2$ and $B^2$ by the function

$$p(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,x_2)$$
Since projection map $p$ is continuous and also bijective, the inverse function $p^{-1}(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,\sqrt{(1-x_1^2-x_2^2)}$ is continous,$p$ is homomorphism between $B$ and the intersection of the first quadrant of  ${\bf R}^2$ and $B^2$.

I think if we could somehow show that the intersection of the first quadrant of ${\bf R}^2$ and $B^2$ are homomorphic, then the proof is complete, but I don't know how...

It would be great if someone can help me figure it out.

Comment: The generic method is to find the two centroids, map one centroid to the other, then for each angle scale each ray in one figure from its centroid to have the length of the (parallel) ray from the centroid of the other figure.  In your case, this will be piecewise, but happily, there are only three pieces...

Comment: well, can you do this one:  show that your closed disc $B^2$  and an inscribed equilateral triangle (including its interior) are homeomorphic.   You could let the triangle vertices be at $(1,0) ; \; ( \frac{-1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}); \;   ( \frac{-1}{2}, \frac{-\sqrt 3}{2});$

Comment: I would guess that if Q be the intersection of the ray from the origin to a point P and the perimeter of the triangle, the function which maps a point P to $\mid Q \mid$*P would be bijective and probably homomorphism although I cannot prove its continuity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $B$ is homeomorphic to $B' =$ intersection of the first quadrant of $\mathbb R^2$ and $B^2$.

In my answer to [Homeomorphism between the unit disc and the unit square](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079355) I constructed a  homeomorphism $f : B^2 \to Q = [-1,1]^2$. It is easy to see that $f(B') = [0,1]^2$, i.e. we have $B' \approx [0,1]^2$.

The square $[0,1]^2$ is clearly homeomorphic to $Q$ and thus homeomorphic to $B^2$.

Comment: One may also add here that every compact convex subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with nonempty interior is homeomorphic to $B^2$ (I think it was discussed on MSE several times).